# c# selecting multiple rows in datagridview by checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have found several related articles and tried them, but couldn't solve the problem. I have a checkbox column in the datagridview of my winForm application. I want to select multiple rows by checking the checkboxes of the adjacant rows and perform some operation on selected rows. But my rows are not getting selected. My code is:

```
this.dgvLoadTable.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgvLoadTable_CellClick);
private void dgvLoadTable_CellClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvLoadTable.Rows)
        {
            //If checked then highlight row

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["Select"].Value))// Select is the name 
                                                             //of chkbox column
            {
                row.Selected = true;
                row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
            }
            else
                row.Selected = false;
        }
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: To start, I suggest you use the `CellContentClick` or `CellValueChanged` (given that you make sure you're clicking on the `Select` cell) events. That will make sure you actually click the checkbox and not the surrounding area of the checkbox. Did you try and debug to see if it actually goes into the foreach loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the `CellValueChanged` event instead of `CellClick` one:

```
private void dgvLoadTable_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvLoadTable.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[3].Value != null && row.Cells[3].Value.Equals(true)) //3 is the column number of checkbox
        {
            row.Selected = true;
            row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
        }
        else
            row.Selected = false;
    }
}
```

And add the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event also:

```
private void dgvLoadTable_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvLoadTable.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dgvLoadTable.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, all of the procedures I have previously tried works fine, including yours. My datagridview was set to readonly, that's why the rows were not getting selected. I am accepting your answer btw.